# How can I use randomly selected variables as R dataframe columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to randomly select sets of variables from a df and use them in a function.
The column names identify n sets (say n=3) of variables, say A & B. So column names are A.1, A.2, …A.n, B.1, B.2, … Bn, etc.. I have randomly selected numbers between 1 and n to identify which set of variables to select. I pasted, e.g., “ A.”  to the random number to get a vector V composed of character variables identifying columns, e.g, “A.3”, “A.1” etc. Now I want to use the values corresponding to column names.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,5,7,4,3,8,2,9,5,5,7,4), 2, 6, 
    dimnames =list(NULL, c('A.1', 'A.2', 'A.3', 'B.1', 'B.2', 'B.3'))))

>df
A.1 A.2 A.3 B.1 B.2 B.3
1   7   3   2   5   7
5   4   8   9   5   4

rando <- c(1,3) # "random" numbers

VA <- paste('A.', rando, sep="")   # A variable names
VB <- paste('B.', rando, sep="")   # B variable names
```

I want a dataframe that looks like this, i.e., with values that came from columns corresponding to to randomly selected numbers:

```
A    B
1    2
8    4
```

I can get the first elements of the table like this: df[1, VA[1]], but I'd like to know how to efficiently generate this table

Comment: Try `df %>% select(all_of(c(VA, VB))) %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = ".value", names_pattern = "([A-Z])\\..*") %>% slice_sample(n = 2)` or it could. be `%>% slice(rando)`

Comment: `df[cbind(c(seq_along(VA), seq_along(VB)), match(c(VA, VB), colnames(df)))]`

Answer (score 0):

The comment by r2Evans solved my problem:

```
ans <- df[cbind(c(seq_along(VA), seq_along(VB)), match(c(VA, VB), colnames(df)))]
```

Then I was able to put it in the desired format with

```
matrix(ans, nrow(df), ncol(df), dimnames=list(NULL, c('VA','VB')))
```